# React: Instantiate component once and use multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to reuse React component twice, but instantiate it only once?

Now I need to trigger timeout on ComponentDidMount, but I need to make only once having several components on the same page. So I thought, maybe it's possible to instantiate component and then pass it as an argument?

For example, there's a component that runs timeout when render complete:

```
export default ComponentOne extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount = () => {
       setTimeout(() => (this.doSomeStuff()), 10 * 1000);
   }

   doSomeStuff = () => {
       // Do something, that can be done only once
   }
}
```

So the component do some stuff that can be done only once. But on the page there are two components that appear depending on screen resolution (css media queries) in different places, like:

```
<div class="page-start block-that-appears-for-desktop">
    <ComponentOne />
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="page-end block-that-appears-for-mobile">
    <ComponentOne />
</div>
```

So now I'll have componentDidMount() called twice and two timeouts, even if one of blocks is hidden.

Comment: Can you share some of your code? I'm a little bit unsure of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should probably move the timeout outside of the Component.

Comment: If you have control on the html code, why not using a prop to tell if the task with the timeout has to be done or not ? Something like `<ComponentOne doTask={true}/>` and then in `componentDidMount` you can test for `this.props.doTask`...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to `doSomeStuff()` only once, it makes sense to extract that function to a higher level component, so that it would be run only once without any additional properties.

You can read more about lifting react state up the hierarchy: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html.